# Why is a reference to a type that implements Fn not recognized as a callable?

Tags: rust, traits, callable

Even if `&T` is defined as implementing the `Fn` trait, the compiler rejects it when invoking it is as a callable:

```
trait Trait {
    fn act(self);
}

//passes
fn test_ref_input_as_trait<'a, T>(t: &'a T)
where
    &'a T: Trait,
{
    t.act();
}

//fails
fn test_ref_input_as_fntrait<'a, T>(t: &'a T)
where
    &'a T: Fn(),
{
    t();
}

//passes
fn test_input_as_fntrait<T>(t: T)
where
    T: Fn(),
{
    t();
}
```

The compiler rejects the definition of the second function with:

```
error[E0618]: expected function, found `&'a T`
  --> src/lib.rs:18:5
   |
14 | fn test_ref_input_as_fntrait<'a, T>(t: &'a T)
   |                                     - `&'a T` defined here
...
18 |     t();
   |     ^^^ not a function
```

With nightly (1.32), the error message is replaced with:

```
error[E0618]: expected function, found `&'a T`
  --> src/lib.rs:18:5
   |
14 | fn test_ref_input_as_fntrait<'a, T>(t: &'a T)
   |                                     - `&'a T` defined here
...
18 |     t();
   |     ^--
   |     |
   |     call expression requires function
```

Maybe I'm missing something, but why is the compiler accepting the definition but not allowing it to be invoked? Is it a syntactical shortcoming from my side that leads it to understand something else?

Comment: Afaik you can't have a reference to a function like that. You can say, that a function should live as long as `'a` with `fn foo<'a, T: Fn() + 'a>(t: T) { t() }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [open issue (#42736)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42736) about this. However, the [docs for `Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) state:

> for any type `F` that implements `Fn`, `&F` implements `Fn`, too.

This means that the following works:

```
fn test_ref_input_as_fntrait<'a, T>(t: &'a T)
where
    T: Fn(),
{
    t();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps a bug (e.g. it works if you replace the `&'a T` by `(&'a T,)`). Nevertheless, you can call the function like this:

```
fn test_ref_input_as_fntrait<'a, T>(t: &'a T)
where
    &'a T: Fn(),
{
    (&t)();
}
```

but since `T: Fn()` automatically implies `&T: Fn()`, it is easier and more idiomatic to just write like your last example.

```
fn test_ref_input_as_fntrait<F: Fn()>(t: F) {
    t();
}

fn main() {
    test_ref_input_as_fntrait(&|| println!("it's okay!"));
}
```